# Java RMI p2p system binding with registry.lookup()

Tags: java, exception, rmi

I am working on a P2P simple system and i have a problem when the client after successfully locates the file on the index server, tries to obtain the file requested. It seems through the research i have already done that there is a problem when binding to the server's rmiregistry which is "CentralIndex" in my case. The client cannot bound the lookup() object. Please HELP!.
Server's code (working great):

```
public class CIServer implements SharedInterface{

Hashtable<String,Integer> rmiregistry;

public CIServer(){
    super();
    this.rmiregistry = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
}

@Override
public int peerSearch(String filename){

    if(rmiregistry.containsKey(filename)){
        return rmiregistry.get(filename);
    }
    System.out.println("The file does not exist.");
    return 1000;
}

@Override
public boolean insertToRegistry(int peerID,String filename){
    rmiregistry.put(filename, peerID);
    return rmiregistry.isEmpty();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "server.policy");
    //System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", "file:/build/classes");

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null){
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }

    try{
    String servername = "CentralIndex";
    SharedInterface handler = new CIServer();        
    SharedInterface stub = (SharedInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(handler,0); 
    Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    reg.rebind(servername, stub);
    System.out.println("CentralIndex service bound");
    }catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println("CentralIndex exception: ");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

client's code:

```
public class RMIClient {
static String ServerName = "CentralIndex";
static int peerID = 1;
static File fileDirectory = new File("Client_files\\");
static String downloadDirectory = "temp";

boolean download(byte[] file, String filename){
    BufferedOutputStream out;
    try{
        out = new BufferedOutputStream
                (new FileOutputStream(downloadDirectory+filename));
        out.write(file, 0, file.length);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("This file path does not exist.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;        
}

void directoryCheck(SharedInterface file){
    String[] subDirectory = fileDirectory.list();
    if (subDirectory == null) {

    }else {
        for (int c = 0; c < subDirectory.length; c++){
            String name = subDirectory[c];
            try{
                file.insertToRegistry(peerID, name);                    
            }catch (RemoteException e){
                System.err.println("Registry error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){        
    RMIClient client = new RMIClient();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int peerAsServerID = 0;
    System.out.println("##############################\n"
            + " Welcome to AARK p2p network. \n"
            + "##############################");
    System.out.println("To search a file just\n"
            + " type the name below: \n -->");
    String filename = in.nextLine();
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "client.policy");
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
    try {
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            SharedInterface handler = (SharedInterface) reg.lookup(ServerName);
            client.directoryCheck(handler);
            peerAsServerID = handler.peerSearch(filename);
            System.out.println(peerAsServerID);

            if (peerAsServerID == 1000){
                System.out.println("No such file.");
            }else {
                System.out.println("File "+filename+" found on peer: "+peerAsServerID);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Handler exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{
            if (peerAsServerID == 1000 || peerAsServerID == 0){
                System.out.println("File:"+filename+" not found.");
            } else{

                String clientAsServerName = String.valueOf(peerAsServerID);     

                Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();

                Handler stub = (Handler)reg.lookup(clientAsServerName);

                byte[] file = stub.obtain(filename);


                if (client.download(file,filename)){
                    System.out.println("Download successful.\n "
                            + "The requested file is at your temp folder.");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Download unsuccessful.\n"
                            + " There was a problem. Please try again.");
                }
            }
         }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Download exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface SharedInterface extends Remote {
int peerSearch (String filename) throws RemoteException;
boolean insertToRegistry(int peerID, String filename) throws RemoteException;
}
```

another interface used by clients as servers:

```
public interface Handler extends Remote {
byte[] obtain(String filename) throws RemoteException;
}
```

and this is finally what i got:

```
file5.txt
File found on peer: 2
Download exception
java.rmi.NotBoundException: 2
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:136)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at RMIClient2.RMIClient2.main(RMIClient2.java:94)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

PLease someone help me fix that asap!
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking up the wrong Registry. You need to lookup the Registry at the server host, not the one at the client. You don't even need a Registry at the client.

Comment: Thank you EJP but what exactly is the problem in my code? Please point me to a direction cause right now i am blind and i cannot see clear. Also my clients also work as servers because this system is like napster where the peers send the files to each other. Do i have two registries? i cannot see some solution. thank you

Comment: As i already said, the problem in your code is that you are looking up the wrong Registry. Check the API for LocateRegistry.getRegistry(). It returns a stub for a registry in the local host. That's not the registry that the server bound to.

Comment: Ok i was not very clear. I got the idea behind your suggestion. it works fine when a client is looking something from the server's registry. but then, once it gets the number of the peer that has the requested file, it should go there and try to obtain the file from that peer. So the search inside the server index is ok. it returns the peerID of the peer that has the file. But then when it tries to pass that peerID through another interface to a class where the client acts as server i get the message that this is not bound. does it even make any sense?

Comment: You need more than the peer ID. You need the peer's *stub.* If you're going to get that from a Registry in the peer host, you also need the IP address of that host. It would be better to have the peer's own stub in the central registry, and have it pass itself (i.e. 'this') to the server as well as its peerID, and have the server bind that into its registry getting rid of the hash table. Then the clients can just lookup the peer directly in the central registry.

Comment: Or else you need something more complicated to provide the peer's own IP[:port] to clients so they can locate its registry and look it up in there. I don't see the value in that, or in all the extra registries.